# Python web scraping: how to print paragraph after a specific class element in browser?

Tags: python, html

I am new to scraping in python (I am using `PyCharm` interface with `Python 3.10`).

I have spent hours trying to troubleshoot this but seems nothing is working. My HTML is of the attached picture format.

[image]

Ideally I want to print the 1st sentence/paragraph after three dots appear in the browser (to separate sections). So the underlined sentences in the attached picture. Amongst others, I have tried the following:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "wp-block-separator has-css-opacity is-style-dots")))
```

and then getting the text with the `XPATH` but unfortunately this does not work. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated and thank you very much!

Comment: as I remember selenium expects single class and it converts it to CSS by adding dot at the beginning but `wp-block-separator has-css-opacity is-style-dots` means three classes which would need dots before every class. It may need to use manually dot to fix this problem `wp-block-separator.has-css-opacity.is-style-dots` (without dot before first class) or you may have to use `CSS selector` with dot even before first class `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wp-block-separator.has-css-opacity.is-style-dots")`

Comment: Hi @furas, thank you very much. The CSS_SELECTOR worked nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember `selenium` expects single class and it converts it to CSS by adding dot at the beginning but `"wp-block-separator has-css-opacity is-style-dots"` means three classes which would need dots before every class.

It may need to use manually dot between classes (without dot before first class) to fix this problem

```
(BY.CLASS_NAME, "wp-block-separator.has-css-opacity.is-style-dots")
```

or you may have to use `CSS selector` with dot even before first class

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wp-block-separator.has-css-opacity.is-style-dots")
```